# Run ruby script and assign to var Groovy/Jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins, groovy

Probably something simple but don't seem to be getting the output i want, but say i have a ruby script

```
class SlackNames

def developers
  { "Richard Lewis" => "/@richlewis",
    "Name 2" => "/@name2",
    "Name 3" => "/@name3"
  }
end

def slack_handle
 puts developers["#{ARGV[0]}"] if developers.key?("#{ARGV[0]}")
end

end

SlackNames.new.slack_handle
```

I would run this on the command line

```
ruby slack_names.rb "Richard Lewis"
```

Which as you can see will just return a keys given value, when i run this in a Groovy script how can i save that value to a variable?

```
-- Groovy
-- DEV_NAME here equals "Richard Lewis"

SLACK_NAME = sh """#!/bin/bash -l
                   ruby ruby_scripts/slack_names.rb \"${DEV_NAME}\"
                """
echo "${SLACK_NAME}"
```

When i echo out `SLACK_NAME` it comes back as blank

What am i doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with Ruby at all. It's about how to get a value from a shell script into groovy. Also there is an error in your Ruby code.

Comment: thanks... would you care to elaborate ?

Comment: The error is that you instantiate the class before ending its declaration. The actual problem? Sorry, I know nothing about Groovy. I'd suggest to adapt your question and reduce it to the essential parts. I.e., remove the ruby part and simply ask People how to store the return value of a shell script in Groovy. The shell script could be `echo "foo"`?

Comment: ah yes i see.. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Richlewis did you manage to figure out how to return values from Ruby script back to Groovy script? I would need exactly the same thing?

Comment: @Buju yes, see my answer at the bottom :-)

Comment: @Richlewis oh, somehow I didn't see that. Thx ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all, you are calling the method from still within the class. (May just be a typo in the post)

Second, why ".key?("#{ARGV[0]}")" thingy? In ruby, if the hash doesn't have a value for a given key, it will just return nil and nil has the boolean value of false.

```
class SlackNames

    def developers
      { "Richard Lewis" => "/@richlewis",
        "Name 2" => "/@name2",
        "Name 3" => "/@name3"
      }
    end

    def slack_handle
     developers["#{ARGV[0]}"] if developers["#{ARGV[0]}"]
    end

end

puts SlackNames.new.slack_handle
```

This works correctly for me at least.

```
ruby slack_names.rb "Richard Lewis"
=> /@richlewis
```

I hope it helps and that I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: Thank you, helped jog memory on a few things.. :-)

Comment: this was not the richard lewis i was thinking of

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to CookieNinjas answer once i added this in groovy everything works as expected

```
SLACK_NAME = sh (
             script: """#!/bin/bash -l
                        ruby ruby_scripts/slack_names.rb \"${DEV_NAME}\"
                     """,
             returnStdout: true
)
```